# Python : Conversion of float to string keeping all digits of decimal place

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a task to count the digits after decimal place.

For which I am using the below code :

```py
str(string_name)[::-1].find('.')
```

But while converting float to string, it is removing the trailing zeroes :

```py
my_string = 16.520440
print(str(my_string ))
```

output - `'16.52044'`

expected output - `'16.520440'`

Comment: Floating point numbers don't have trailing zeros, only strings do.

Comment: If you need floating-point numbers with a fixed degree of precision, consider using the [`Decimal` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead.

Comment: You should be aware that the value you enter as a numeric literal `16.520440` is actually being stored as `16.52044000000000067984728957526385784149169921875` (platform-dependent, but almost certainly true in practice). So the number of digits after the decimal place is 47 in this case. That's probably not what you want, so you may well want to use `Decimal` instead. (On the other hand, what's this actually for?)

Answer (score 4):

Since that trailing zero is not a significant digit, there is no way you can do this within the given paradigm.  Floats are stored by *value*, not by the visual representation of the original input.  For instance:

```
my_string_1 =  16.52044
my_string_2 =  16.520440
my_string_3 =  16.5204400
my_string_4 = 016.5204400
```

All assign *exactly* the same value to the LHS variable: they have the same binary representation.  Leading and trailing zeros do not, *by definition*, affect this value.  There is no way to differentiate the original input from the stored value.

If you want some such effect, then you need to use some other form of original value that incorporates that information.  For instance, you could add a second variable that denotes the quantity of significant decimal places -- which is the opposite of what you're trying to achieve -- or perhaps make the original input a string, from which you could derive that information.

Comment: In fact, under CPython, if you put those four lines into a file `my_strings.py` and then do `from my_strings import *` at an interpreter prompt, not only do all four names represent the same value - they all refer to the exact same `float` object, in the sense that e.g. `my_string_1 is my_string_4` gives `True`. (Thanks to constant folding during parsing.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: thanks for the observation, because (most?) other Python implementations don't perform this real-time constant folding.  My CenotOS-based Python 3.6.8 gives me the (expected) four distinct IDs.

Comment: Hmm. I do see the constant folding with Python 3.6.9, too (on macOS). But it does matter that the file is imported, rather than the lines being entered at the prompt one-by-one.